# How to put @beanmapping ignored by default to false from JDL

Tags: java, jhipster, mapstruct, jdl

I'm trying to generate my entities and dtos from a JDL file, and I need that mapper files put *@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault=false)* for recovering all the properties of a relationship's dto and not only the id. But when I generate dtos from JDL file ignoredByDefault is set to true. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

What I got in my jdl file (after my entities and relationships parts) is:

dto * with mapstruct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way as you can easily find out by looking at the [EntityMapper template](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/entity-server/templates/src/main/java/package/service/mapper/EntityMapper.java.ejs#L106) in generator's code: this line is not conditional at all.

So, the easy way is to modify generated code manually, the hard way would be to write a blueprint but it seems overkill.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks a lot! I can stop wasting time.